# 100% width in bootstrap for iPhone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using bootstrap for a simple HTML5, CSS3 website.(see here:  http://skyfistudio.com/project/fsc/ ) .there are three divs that should be 100% width.

It's looking good in desktop and all browsers. But in iPhone , it shows aligned left(Please see the attached image). I want it to stretch 100%. The iPhone view is here:

http://skyfistudio.com/project/fsc/hosting/

Here is the code for first navigation:

```
ul.fnav
   {
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:0;
   padding-top:8px;
   padding-bottom:8px;
   text-align:center;
   margin-top:0px;
   background-color:#3B5998;
   width:100%;
   }

ul.fnav li
     {
      display:inline;
     }

 ul.fnav a:link,ul.fnav a:visited
     {
      font-weight:normal;
      color:#fff;
      margin-left:10px;
      font-size:13px;
      text-align:center;
      padding:6px;
      margin-right:55px;
      text-decoration:none;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
     }

   ul.fnav a:hover,a:active
    {
      color:#ccc;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Place them inside a `<div class="container-fluid">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Make Both  and the image div in one div so that bot come in one row-fluid and also check with @media-queries in custom.css